# Allow non-root user to set system time

Tags: raspbian, systemd, user, system-clock

I am using Raspbian Buster on an Raspberry Pi 4.  I would like to give permissions to a non-root user to be able to set the time with `/bin/date -s`.  The user is going to be used to run a python script using a systemd service.  I have tried following the instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78309/270299) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454810/270299) without success.  Those posts were not for Raspbian but I checked and it seems Debian [uses the same thing](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/libcap2-bin/capability.conf.5.en.html).

One thing I tried while troubleshooting was to set pam_cap.so to required instead of optional, but then when running the `su` command it says `su: Module is unknown`, which seems to indicate that it can't find pam_cap.so at all...  I confirmed I have `libcap2` and `libcap2-bin` installed though so I am not sure what I am missing...  EDIT:  I did a search for pam_cap.so on the system and couldn't find it, so that part makes sense I suppose...  Does anyone know how to install it?

The specific steps I have taken are:

```
sudo useradd tasks_user
sudo sed '/pam_rootok.so/i auth        optional    pam_cap.so' /etc/pam.d/su -i
sudo setcap CAP_SYS_TIME+ei /bin/date

sudo su - tasks_user
capsh --print
```

I've tried restarting at every point in the process but it doesn't help.  I confirmed that running `sudo setcap CAP_SYS_TIME+ep /bin/date` works, but this gives access to all users, which is not ideal...

Comment: Note sure why the user needs to change the date - I could see lots off issues but it's your machine.  Have you looked at using the sudoers file and allowing the date command for that user in it?

Comment: You could always copy the date binary to a directory in the user's home and permit no one else to access the directory, then setcap that copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like pam_cap.so can be installed with the `libpam-cap` package, which seems obvious in retrospect...  After that everything worked as expected.

The reason I am marking this as the correct answer is because I would prefer not to have to use sudo for some commands and not others, which is what would be required if editing the sudoers file as suggested in joan's answer.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you allow the command to be issued with `sudo`.  This would remind the user that they are using a privileged command.

`sudo visudo`

then add the following line to the end of the file

`tasks_user  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/date`

The tasks_user can issue the command using sudo.

E.g.

```
tasks_user:~$ sudo date -s "2020-05-23 16:31:10"
Sat 23 May 16:31:10 BST 2020
```